# Vertical alignment of text within a Gliffy shape

Tags: gliffy

Given a basic container shape on a *Gliffy* diagram : we can see the *Text* formatting options only show *horizontal* alignment options:

[image]

This is in contradiction to some documentation that I had found:

https://guide.gliffy.com/user-manual/gliffy-for-jira-plugin/1/en/topic/changing-text-position-in-a-shape

[image]

I'm not sure: is this a *versioning* issue?  I am an end user of a corporate *confluence* / *wiki* account and do not have visibility into the version they are using.  Any workarounds available?

Comment: how would that help ? will only create a _long_ textbox, not a top -positioned one.

Comment: I did see that question: it does not show how to position  text vertically within a shape: also it does not include mention of the documentation I showed in this question